# Creating a factory - provide data in constructor or as parameter?

Tags: java

I'm creating a factory method that should wrapp some object creation. Question: would you rather provide the needed data in a constructor, or as param for the methods itself?

```
class PersonFactory {
    //constructor only neccessary of no param in method
    public PersonFactory(PersonDTO dto) {
        this.dto = dto;
    }

    public Person createPerson(PersonDTO dto) {
        //create the complex person
        return person;
    }

    //more methods to come
}
```

What would you prever, and why?

```
new PersonFactory(dto).createPerson();
new PersonFactory().createPerson(dto);
```

Comment: This isn't even a *choice*. If in doubt, provide both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options are valid.

It depends on whether you want to reach around factories which have their `dto` property already set or if you know that property only when you use the factory.

When the classes which use the factory shouldn't depend on the `PersonDTO` (whatever that is), it would make sense to have that attached as a private property to the factory.

But when the PersonDTO is an object which is created by the user of the factory, you would provide it to the create-method.

Answer (score 0):

I would pick the new PersonFactory().createPerson(dto); because its more convenient. You dont need to make new instances of the factory class if you wish to create more objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the

```
 createPerson(dto)
```

for me this is easier to test.
Also in such a case you do not actually need an instance of PersonFactory - you could simply make the method static.

Answer (score 0):

The design rule I use for factories is:

- Do the heavy work in the constructor
- Make factory instances reusable (and ideally thread safe)
- Do instance related stuff in the method

That means, I'd go with the `new PersonFactory().createPerson(dto)` approach.

Even if both ways were valid in this example, it is easier to follow one standard approach for all the factories you create. That way your code is much easier to understand later.